# Convert Binary content of PDF file To JSON format using node.js

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules

we want Json format from binary content of pdf file using node.js.

Actually we are getting  binary content of pdf from 3 party api response , using this response we will save in our database ,so give me working code for convert binary pdf format to json format

in simple words
Please let us know , "any working code so i have just pass binary data got json data" .

Answer (score 1):

**The JSON format natively doesn't support binary data.**
Use Base64 or base85

I think the best you can do space-wise is base85 which represents four bytes as five characters. However, this is only a 7% improvement over base64, it's more expensive to compute, and implementations are less common than for base64 so it's probably not a win.